# Error Deleting Azure AD

Tags: azure

I'm trying to delete my Ad, but the system says that I cannot delete it because "there is an Application using it.

When I go to Application Tab, it just show me Visual Studio Online (with [www.visualstudio.com](http://www.visualstudio.com) url) and did not show an option to delete... How can I do to remove it?

> Note: I've tried to create another Azure account, but the system tells
>   me that I've already created my mycompany.onmicrosoft.com

Comment: You need to unlink VSO from the directory.

Answer (score 0):

A global administrator can delete an Azure AD directory from the portal. When a directory is deleted, all resources contained in the directory are also deleted; so you should be sure you don’t need the directory before you delete it.

There are some conditions before you can delete the AD from portal because it will impact the users or Applications.

- global administrator who will delete the AD
- sync will need to be turned off if you are using in house AD to Azure
- Other users must be deleted in the cloud directory by using the Management Portal or the Azure module for Windows PowerShell.
- Any applications must be deleted before the AD can be deleted.
- Make sure there is no online subscription connected with AD.
- Check in Azure management ? settings for more info.

I hope you can resolve your issue quicker.
Let me know the outcome.

Regards